# Oracle SQL error handling: catching the SQL-statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, error-handling, backtrace

In PL/SQL, in my exception handlers I use `dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace` to catch the backtrace of errors. When I run into a primary key violation in a procedure, this returns the following error message:

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (MY_USER.MY_TABLE_PK) violated ORA-06512: at line 41
```

So now I know the primary key MY_TABLE_PK was violated at line 41. What I would like to know is the actual SQL-statement that caused this primary key violation, so I would like my error message to include something like `INSERT INTO MY_TABLE ...` if that is what happens at line 41.

Does anyone know how to do that?

**EDIT:**

I know the statement can be found in line 41. However, that is not what I am asking. What I ask is how to include the SQL-statement that caused the error in my error message.

Comment: You editor should be able to show line 41

Comment: May be this can help https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CSBE3ZJTSXBTUEI174J84WGO0.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PL/SQL developer how to get the row that made the insert fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838446/pl-sql-developer-how-to-get-the-row-that-made-the-insert-fail)

Comment: Is you need to find an SQL statement which fails, it is at line 41 in your code (but there are some possibilities to make this information wrong). If you want to know which data causes the error, see my comment above.

Comment: @XING, I mentioned the backtrace in my question, that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: It looks a bit clunky but you could 'wrap' each update that you are interested in with a BEGIN...END block with an exception to tailor the output to whatever you want. I don't personally like this as it makes the code look clunky and you need to be careful how the errors are then raised but if that is the requirement . . .

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this where you can't use an editor to show you the code in the db you can do the following;

```
SELECT line, text
FROM   all_source
WHERE  line BETWEEN :err_line - 10 AND :err_line + 10 AND name = :pkg
```

Comment: This will not always work, for example when in the above example around line nr. 41 the statement is built up dynamically. Then your suggestion will return the arguments that were used...

Comment: @Eric12345 - OP makes no mention of dynamic SQL so I didn't consider it. However, given the clarification this answer is definitely not useful so I will delete it.